# My Python file connected through the right path with my sqlite database but couldn't identify a table in that database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, backend

I want to connect my SQLite database/ or I think I'm connecting my "data.sqlite" (the blue highligted one in the picture below)  with my views.py in the core folder (picture below) with:

```
rPath='../../Upchanges/data.sqlite'
conn = _sqlite3.connect(rPath, check_same_thread=False)  
c = conn.cursor()
```

Path of the database I want to connect with:
Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges/data.sqlite

Path of the Python file I want to connect with the database:
Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges/core/views.py

Picture of my file orientation:

[image]

**So this is my problem:**
I later use these codes below in my python file:

```
from Upchanges.models import BlogPost( I set the __tablename__ to 'blog_post' in another python file)
@core.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    search = Blogsearch_form(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE problem_name LIKE(?)", ('%' + str(search) + '%',))
        results = c.fetchall()
        print(results)
        return render_template('blog_search_result.html', results=results)



    page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
    many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('index.html', many_posts=many_posts, form=search)
```

When I input something and click enter in the Blogsearch_form, my website shows this error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: blog_post". I also tried replacing blog_post with BlogPost but it shows the same error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: BlogPost"

I promise you I have a blog_post table in my data.sqlite database. I use it also in some codes below and my website query the data and work just fine (show everything later on in the HTML file):

```
page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
    many_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('index.html', many_posts=many_posts, form=search)
```

Addtionally, for more clarity, these codes below (which is in the **init**.py of my app.py file) are those that create my data.sqlite database:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir,
                                                                    '../Upchanges/data.sqlite')
```

So, I really think that something is wrong with the path in the _sqlite3.connect command. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me fix the problem above.
(Please use the picture when you think about the path as it is easier to imagine)

Thank you!!

P.s/ I tried this from my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849867/13097721 but I still couldn't fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you do not necessarily know from which directory the application has been started from.

You could test this with

```
import os
print("My current working directory is", os.getcwd())
```

However if your database is located relative to a python file, then it is better to determine the path relative to the python file's directory than trying to determine it relative to the current working directory.

You can do this for example with with

```
import os
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
SQLPATH = os.path.join(MYDIR, "..", "..", "data.sqlite")
```

I also suggest to add following line in your existing code or in your modified code.
It will show you exactly where you point to

```
print("THE REAL SQLPATH is", os.path.realpath(SQLPATH))
```

**Comment after your feedback:**
I Will add more prints (and remove one `".."`) but you will see what you need to do with two more prints.

```
import os
print("MY FILE = ", os.path.realpath(__file__))
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print("MYDIR = ", os.path.realpath(MYDIR))
SQLPATH = os.path.join(MYDIR, "..", "data.sqlite")
print("This gives me SQLPATH = ", os.path.realpath(SQLPATH))
```

**Comment after next Feedback**

So it seems how, that the database file is now properly located.

I suggest to inspect your database.

from a shell window type:

```
sqlite3  /Users/kienletrung/Desktop/Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges/data.sqlite
```

type then commands like 
`.tables` to list all tables `.schema <tablename>` to look at a tables format. or `select * from tablename;` to look at all rows of a table.

alternatively just type:

```
echo .dump | sqlite3 /Users/kienletrung/Desktop/Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges/data.sqlite  > fulldump.txt
```

to create a full ascii dump of your database.

If you don't have the sqlite command line client installed then just install it. It should simplify debugging.

You can of course use any other tool to inspect your data base in look at what tables / structures your python code expects and what the database really contains.

Comment: Hi gelonida! Thank you so much for helping me. I tried print(os.getcwd()) before the c.execute... and got this path "/Users/kienletrung/Desktop/Upchanges_desperate". Also, when I tried your codes "MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
SQLPATH = os.path.join(MYDIR, "..", "..", "data.sqlite")
conn = _sqlite3.connect(SQLPATH, check_same_thread=False)  
c = conn.cursor()", my python file automatically create a blank data.sqlite database in my biggest folder Upchanges_desperate. But I want to connect with my data.sqlite database in the folder Upchanges ,which is inside the folder Upchanges_desperate

Comment: Hmm if I get it right, then just remove one `".."` from the `os.path.join()` but to be sure look at my modified answer and add a few more prints.
It should become obvious what to do.
It all depends in which file this code is placed. I'm not sure about this.

Perhaps you have to remove or add another ".." in the `os.path.join()` statement

Comment: I remove on ".." and add more prints like you suggest. I got the following results in my terminal: MY FILE =  /Users/kienletrung/Desktop/Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges/core/views.py
MYDIR =  /Users/kienletrung/Desktop/Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges/core
This gives me SQLPATH =  /Users/kienletrung/Desktop/Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges/data.sqlite I see that the path to connect my data.sqlite database is absolutely right but it still show the error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: BlogPost" when my python file run c.execute("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE...

Comment: Thank you for your next help! I don't know if this will help, but I think after I used the codes above, it create another data.sqlite in the same place. Which is data [2] in the picture I just added in my answer above. I query table blog_post in this data[2]( which is the clone version of data.sqlite) ok but when I tried query table blog_post in data, it didn't work. I think that my python file is connecting with the first database.

Comment: Hi @gelonida! I used my Mac terminal, used your codes and successfully query data from my data.sqlite database. So now the problem is really about why my codes create another exactly same data.sqlite database, use it and couldn't identify the blog_post table in it. Does it has anything to do with me not putting this codes "sqlite3 ../../data.sqlite< schema.sql" in my terminal?

Comment: I'm at a loss.
There can be no two files with the same name in the same directory.

perhaps you can use the command line and make `ls -ltra` of the directory where you have the two files. You will see hidden files, the exact suffixes and when the file was last modified. Example `ls -ltra /Users/kienletrung/Desktop/Upchanges_desperate/Upchanges`
If this is the directory where your sql file is located

Comment: Uh, gelonida. I fixed it and it's thank to you.. :)

Comment: Hi @gelonida, I have another problem related to python and sqlite and I'm hoping if you could also help me in it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61886605/13097721 Thank you!